# How to return the first character of a string if it's repeating?

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison

How can I check if the first character in a string is repeating or not? I can't find the answer anywhere!

```
char HamBurger(String s){

    for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s[i]==s[0]){
            return s[0];
        }
    }
    return "_";
}
```

It's giving me errors like this

```
file.java on line 4: error: array required, but 
String found
        if(s[i]==s[j]){
            ^
file.java on line 4: error: array required, but 
String found
        if(s[i]==s[j]){
                  ^
file.java on line 5: error: array required, but 
String found
            return s[j];
                    ^
```

Sorry, I'm transitioning from C++ to Java, it's all very new to me!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write Java as if it were C, but as you're finding out,  it's not. Don't guess, but instead do have a look at one of the many decent tutorials that are available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method:

```
char HamBurger(String s){

    for(int i=1;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(0)){
            return s.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    return '_';
}
```

The `[]` syntax is used with `Array`'s.

---

You can also utilize the [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) method to check if there is any other `char` that matches the first letter:

```
public static char HamBurger(String s){
    return s.lastIndexOf(s.charAt(0)) == 0 ? '_' : s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Why `lastIndexOf(x) == 0` and not `indexOf(x, 1) < 0`?

Comment: @Andreas My logic was that if the last index of the letter was the first one, then there's only one of the letter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're taking an iterative approach, you should use the method `charAt(i)` on the string you're iterating through. The string is not a primitive array of chars in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Check your errors, you passed your variable `s` which is a `String` but you accessed its characters by using the same variable (which is `s`) as `array`, thus giving you the error.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if the first letter of your string occurred again anywhere else in the same string and return that character if it does. So here's my solution:

```
char HamBurger(String s){

    for(int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(i)){
            return s.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    return '_';
}
```

or if you want to ignore the casing, you can change your `if` condition to

```
if(s.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == s.toLowerCase().charAt(i)){
   //code
}
```